# Is this a correct 'trick' to find the limit of a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say I'm given a sequence of the form $c_n = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ and I'm asked to find its limit but I don't know how to do it directly. Is it correct for me to say that its limit is $\frac{l_a}{l_b}$, where $l_a = \lim a_n$ and $l_b = \lim b_n$, with $l_b \ne 0$?

Comment: This is true IF both limits that you just mentioned exist.

Comment: @Graphth Of course.

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't hit an indeterminate form.

Comment: See http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Sequences/Quotient_Rule for the proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if both limits exist and the denominator is nonzero, then this is correct (and usually by far the easiest way to find the limit).

Ultimately this is because the function $(x,y)\mapsto \frac xy$ is continuous for $y\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true IF both limits that you just mentioned exist.  An easy example is $a_n = b_n = n$.  Then, $c_n = \frac{n}{n}$, which has limit $1$, but $\lim\limits a_n = \lim\limits b_n = \infty$.  In the case of such an indeterminate form, then l'Hopital's rule might be your best tool.